# mongoDB count distinct objects after aggregate of 3 collections

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate, distinct

MongoShell version 4.0.2

I have 3 collections with data correlation between collections

**B:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8f83fb520b3ea906ac11d1"), 
    "X" : "002100367752", 
    "Z" : "002KV180054605",
}
```

**A :**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8f83fa520b3e09e7ac0de1"), 
    "Y" : "002100367752" 
}
```

**C :**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b8f83fb520b3e0127ac15b9"), 
    "N" : "002KV180054605", 
    "Q" : 17, 
    "W" : 1, 
    "E" : 35 
}
```

The connection looks like this:

```
Collection A <> Collection B <> Collection C
```

Only in Collection B I have ID of objects from all 3 collections

Now, I want to count the distinct number of objects in collection A that are connected via Collection B to objects from Collection C that have specific parameters.

This means my count should return number of distinct objects from Collection A that can have multiple connections with objects from collection C

[image: Connection schema]

If I query like below I get no results:

```
db.B.aggregate([
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "A",
            localField: "X",
            foreignField: "Y",
            as: "Acc"
        }
   },
   {
      $match: { "Acc": { $ne: [] } }
   },
   {
      $lookup:
         {
            from: "C",
            localField: "Z",
            foreignField: "N",
            as: "Con"
        }
   },
   {
      $match: { "Con": { Q: 1, W: 1, E: 9 } }
   }
])
```

Also, I have no idea how to do count for this query

Comment: Could you post an example of your dataset and your expected result?
So we can try out in local :)
Thanks!

Comment: I can share only anonymized example, I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

I think this is my solution:

```
    db.idlsfcontractroles.aggregate([
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"idlsfcontracts",
    "localField":"Contract__r_ExternalId__c",
    "foreignField":"ExternalId__c",
    "as":"Con"
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$Con"},
  {"$match":{"Con.Status__c":1,"Con.Type__c":1,"Con.ConductingCompany__c":31}},
  {"$group":{"_id": null, uniqueValues: {$addToSet: "$Account__r_MDMExternalId__c"}}},
  {"$project": {"_id": 1, numberOfParties: { $size: "$uniqueValues" }}}
])
```

Comment: your last two stages can be `{"$group":{"_id":"$Account__r_MDMExternalId__c"}},
  {"$count": "numberOfParties"}`